# Why doesn't variable increment in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Given;

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,0,1,2],
     [3,4,5,6]]
```

I want to get a list of the diagonal - using a single list comprehension statement.

```
[1,6,1,6]
```

I expected that I could do so with

```
i = -1 # (cheating but I didn not know how else to do it)
dia_1 = [r[i] for (r,i) in [(r, i+1) for r in a]]
```

but I get as a result;

```
[1, 5, 9, 3]
```

So, i must not be incrementing:

**Q1:** Why doesn't 'i' increment?

**Q2:** How to fix the statement to achieve the desirede result?

Comment: Which part do you expect to increment `i`? There is no assignment anywhere...

Comment: @MadPhysicist; Yeah - I feel kinda dumb when you ask it that way. I guess it just seemed like it should : )

Comment: you dont need to i assignment use enumerate instead.. check our answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not something like

```
dia_1 = [a[n][n] for n in range(len(a))]
```

or

```
dia_1 = [r[n] for n, r in enumerate(a)]
```

While the second approach is more aesthetically pleasing to me personally, they yield identical results. Both assume that the `n`th row has an `n`th element, regardless of the actual shape of the list.

To answer your question about incrementing, there is no assignment to `i` anywhere in your comprehension. `i + 1` has the constant value `0`, so you are fetching the first column, as expected.

Comment: I didn't even know about enumerate -- that alone was worth feeling a little dumb about my question. Thank you.

Comment: You ask a reasonable question, you learn something new. Don't worry about feeling dumb, it just means you learned a thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't 'i' increment?

Because you never told it to. Nor can you.

> How to fix the statement to achieve the desirede result?

Do it completely differently.

```
[r[e] for e, r in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try `enumerate(a)` hope this is you ant...

i got output

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,0,1,2],
     [3,4,5,6]]
dia_1 = [r[i] for i,r in enumerate(a)]    
print(dia_1)

>>>[1, 6, 1, 6]
```

Comment: Why do you have a nested comprehension?

Comment: i am just overwritten OP code... he try to iterate i so used enumerate instead

Comment: See the other two answers for an example of what I am talking about. Why do you feel that it is a good idea to reverse the order of the enumeration tuple?

Comment: sorry @MadPhysicist i updated my answer ... i thought to do in OP way forgot to short it.. thanks done (y)

Comment: Oh, I see. OP was doing that weirdness too.

Comment: focused to solve forgot to noticed unwanted things.. upvoted your answer for help me to sort out

Answer (score 0):

The main diagonal can be extracted in following way:

```
dia_1 = [a[i][i] for i in range(len(a[0]))]
```

Comment: Why not just `len(a)`? What if `len(a) == 0`?

Comment: if len(a)==0 You can always catch exceptions, but I see drawback in this. using enumerate is much better in such case `dia_1 = [r[i] for i,r in enumerate(a)] `

Comment: @
SteveJ `i=-1 
dia_1 = [r[i] for (r,i) in [(r, i+1) for r in a]]` gets the first column of Your array. If You wnnt to get differnt column you can use 
'c=2 
dia_1 = [r[i] for (r,i) in [(r, i+c) for r in a]'